# Maze collision detection with tiles AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, maze

Hey guys so I created a maze with this code and I want to hitTest the walls but when i try something along the lines of if (mc.hitTestObject(tile)) it doesn't do anything. And I'm not sure why, here's the code :

```
package  
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;


public class Main extends MovieClip
{


    private var mc:hero = new hero;
    private var tile:tile1 = new tile1; 
    private var mcSpeed:uint = 5;

    private var lab1Array:Array = new Array;
    private const TILE_WIDTH:uint = 25;
    private const TILE_HEIGHT:uint = 25;
    private const STAGE_WIDTH:uint = 550;
    private const STAGE_HEIGHT:uint = 400;
    private var horizontalBlocks = STAGE_WIDTH / TILE_WIDTH;
    private var verticalBlocks = STAGE_HEIGHT / TILE_HEIGHT;
    private var hitBlock:DisplayObject;


    private var leftDown: Boolean = false;
    private var rightDown: Boolean = false;
    private var botDown: Boolean = false;
    private var upDown: Boolean = false;



    public function Main() 
    {


        mc.x = 160;
        mc.y = 385;
        addChild(mc);


        for (var i:uint = 0 ; i < verticalBlocks ;  i++)
        {
            lab1Array[i] = new Array;

            for (var j:uint=0; j < horizontalBlocks; j++)
                {
                lab1Array[i].push(0);
                }


        }


         lab1Array = [
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
        ];



        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, checkKeysUp);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, charManagement);

    }


    function checkKeysDown (event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {


        if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65) 
        {
            leftDown = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87) 
        {
            upDown = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68) 
        {
            rightDown = true;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83) 
        {
            botDown = true;
        }
    }

    function checkKeysUp (event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {   
        if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 65) 
        {
            leftDown = false;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 87) 
        {
            upDown = false;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 68) 
        {
            rightDown = false;
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 40 || event.keyCode == 83) 
        {
            botDown = false;
        }
    }

    function charManagement(event:Event) : void
    {


            if (leftDown)
            {
                mc.x -= mcSpeed;
            }
            if (rightDown)
            {
                mc.x += mcSpeed;
            }
            if (upDown)
            {
                mc.y -= mcSpeed;
            }
            if (botDown)
            {
                mc.y += mcSpeed;
            }

    }

        function createLab():void 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < lab1Array.length ; i++) 
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < lab1Array[i].length ; j++)
              {
                    if (lab1Array[i][j] == 1)
                  {
                        tile= new tile1;
                        tile.x = TILE_WIDTH*(j+0.5);
                        tile.y = TILE_HEIGHT*(i+0.5);
                        addChild(tile);

                  } 

              } 

         }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the code where you do your `mc.hitTestObject(tile)` test ? Because here, I don't see any collision part in this code.

Comment: It didn't work so i removed it but I wanted to put it in the charManagement function that checks every frame and do something like : if (mc.hitTestObject(tile) == true && leftDown) { }
else if (leftDown && mc.hitTestObject(tile) == false) { mc.x -= mcSpeed; }
And this with every arrow but it doesn't work =(

Comment: Ok in fact i realised that when i hitTest the "tile" it only tests the last one created. Any idea on how to hitTest all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give an answer based off of your code, but hitTestObject should be inside of the key down detection inside the CharManagement function

```
if(leftDown)
{
 mc.x += mcSpeed;
 if mc.hitTestObject(tiles)
 {
  //add code for whatever you want to do
 }
}
```

I would also need to see your tile1 class, because i believe that it is possibly not an object, hence why hittestObject was never returning true.

P.S. when you say it wasnt working, does that mean it gave you errors? or it just didnt accomplish what you wanted?

Comment: It doesn't do anything but doesn't cause any errors. My tile1 class is empty actually, just created it to make the maze with tiles. I tried what you suggested but it doesn't give any result either. I'm confused, do I have to hit test "tile" or something else?

Comment: Ok in fact i realised that when i hitTest the "tile" it only tests the last one created. Any idea on how to hitTest all of them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tile to hit test for the player
This is done by using an update function in the tile class, instead of the one you are currently using. This is done like so
mc.hittestobject(this);