# Wall detection between MovieClip and lines Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random, maze, color-detection

I found a random maze generator for Actionscript-3 online.[This is the maze I found](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/11/28/perfect-maze-generation-with-as3/).  I tweaked it a bit and now I need to figure out a way to test if the player has hit a wall.  I don't know how to test if the player has hit the walls or is over the start and finish.  Here's my code.

```
gotoAndStop(3)
graphics.beginFill(0xffffff, 1);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
graphics.endFill();
graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 600);
graphics.endFill();
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;
var Player:player = new player();
addChild(Player)
var mazeW=26;
var mazeH=19;
var wall_size=20;
var startP = Point;
var finishP = Point;
var maze = new Array();
var moves = new Array();
var draw:Sprite = new Sprite();
var cells=mazeW*mazeH;
//this just makes the random starts and finishes
//var RNum:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*3); 
//trace(RNum);
var RNum = 0
var pos=Math.floor(Math.random()*cells);
var visited=1;
for (var i=0; i<cells; i++) {
    maze[i]=new Array(0,1,1,1);
}
if (RNum == 0){
    startP = new Point(1, 1);
    finishP = new Point(mazeW, mazeH);
    graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(10, 10, 20, 20);
    graphics.endFill();
    graphics.beginFill(0x32CD32, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(510, 370, 20, 20);
    graphics.endFill();
    Player.x = 520;
    Player.y = 378;
    Player.width = 14; 
    Player.height = 10; 

}
if (RNum == 1){
    graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(510, 10, 20, 20);
    graphics.endFill();
    graphics.beginFill(0x32CD32, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(10, 370, 20, 20);
    graphics.endFill();

}
if (RNum == 2){
    graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(10, 370, 20, 20);
    graphics.endFill();
    graphics.beginFill(0x32CD32, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(510, 10, 20, 20);
    graphics.endFill();


}
if (RNum == 3){
    graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(510, 370, 20, 20);
    graphics.endFill();
    graphics.beginFill(0x32CD32, 1);
    graphics.drawRect(10, 10, 20, 20);
    graphics.endFill();
}
maze[pos][0]=1;
while (visited<cells) {
    var possible="";
    if (((pos-mazeW)>=0) && (maze[pos-mazeW][0] == 0)) {
        possible=possible+"N";
    }  
    if (((pos+mazeW)<cells) && (maze[pos+mazeW][0] == 0)) {
        possible=possible+"S";
    }
    if ((Math.floor(pos/mazeW) == Math.floor((pos+1)/mazeW)) && (maze[pos+1][0] == 0)) {
        possible=possible+"E";
    }
    if ((Math.floor(pos/mazeW) == Math.floor((pos-1)/mazeW)) && (maze[pos-1][0] == 0)) {
        possible=possible+"W";
    }
    if (possible) {
        visited++;
        moves.push(pos);
        var way=possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*possible.length));
        switch (way) {
            case "N" :
                maze[pos][1]=0;
                maze[pos-mazeW][2]=0;
                pos-=mazeW;
                break;
            case "S" :
                maze[pos][2]=0;
                maze[pos+mazeW][1]=0;
                pos+=mazeW;
                break;
            case "E" :
                maze[pos][3]=0;
                maze[pos+1][4]=0;
                pos++;
                break;
            case "W" :
                maze[pos][4]=0;
                maze[pos-1][3]=0;
                pos--;
                break;
        }
        maze[pos][0]=1;
    } else {
        pos=moves.pop();
    }
}
addChild(draw);
draw.graphics.lineStyle(3,0x89A84A);
draw.graphics.moveTo(10,10);
var start_y=10-wall_size;
var start_x=0;
for (i=0; i<cells; i++) {
    start_x+=wall_size;
    if ((i%mazeW) == 0) {
        start_y+=wall_size;
        start_x=10;
    }
    if (maze[i][2]==1) {
        draw.graphics.moveTo(start_x,start_y+wall_size);
        draw.graphics.lineTo(start_x+wall_size,start_y+wall_size);
    }
    if (maze[i][3]==1) {
        draw.graphics.moveTo(start_x+wall_size,start_y);
        draw.graphics.lineTo(start_x+wall_size,start_y+wall_size);
    }
}

draw.graphics.lineStyle(4,0x89A84A);
draw.graphics.moveTo(10,10);
draw.graphics.lineTo(10+wall_size*mazeW,10);
draw.graphics.lineTo(10+wall_size*mazeW,10+wall_size*mazeH);
draw.graphics.lineTo(10,10+wall_size*mazeH);
draw.graphics.lineTo(10,10);
```

I thought about trying to decect the color of the lines and trying to generate the walls with an instance name, but never figured it out.  Any ideas?

edit: I cannot use hit test object since the lines are not symbols, is thier any other way to detect collisions

Comment: Related, probably: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21100699/1531971

Comment: @jdv look at my edit this is my main problem

Comment: SO works best with a specific question, but it looks like you are asking about how to implement how to detect end-game and wall detection. This is more of a research question that is a poor fit for this site.